# Change classes of item divs inside bootstrap `row` class div on click

Tags: jquery, html

This code is used to define a bootstrape `row` class on a div:

```
<div class="row">
    <br />
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Snacks">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="~/XImages/snacks.png" />
         </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/baby.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/personal-care.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/beverages.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I need to change all item divs with class `col-sm-4` to `col-sm-1` when div with `col-sm-4` class is clicked.

Can someone please guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery below registers a click on any element with the class `.col-sm-4`, travels up the DOM tree to the nearest `.row` and then switches the classes of any immediate children.

This deliberately doesn't propogate throughout grandchildren etc to avoid issues.

Hopefully this is what you wanted.

```
$(".col-sm-4").click( function() {

  $(this).closest(".row").children(".col-sm-4").removeClass("col-sm-4").addClass("col-sm-1");

});
```

---

## Alternative

Even better... you can use .toggleClass to switch the two classes, and add the trigger events dynamically in case you are creating new rows.

```
$(".row").on("click", ".rowitem", function() {

  $(this).closest(".row").children(".rowitem").toggleClass("col-sm-4").toggleClass("col-sm-1");

});
```

## Demo

```js
$(document).on("click", ".rowitem", function() {

  $(this).closest(".row").children(".rowitem").toggleClass("col-sm-4").toggleClass("col-sm-1");

});
```

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  background: white;
}
.col-sm-1 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <br />
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Snacks">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="~/XImages/snacks.png" />
         </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/baby.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/personal-care.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/beverages.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
    <br />
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem" id="Snacks">
        <a href="#">
             <img src="~/XImages/snacks.png" />
         </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/baby.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/personal-care.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 rowitem">
         <img src="~/XImages/beverages.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```